# Jenkins build proceeds even though SCM poll finds no changes

Tags: svn, version-control, jenkins

I have a Jenkins jobs setup to poll SCM nightly and run a build if there are changes. The problem is if there are no changes, Jenkins executes the job anyway.

Here is console output of a simple job that polls SCM and then executes a single build step (shell command of "echo blah").

Here is a link to the console output:
[image: image of console output]
As you can see, even though there were no SCM changes, the build continues. The behavior I am looking for is if there is no change, the build steps are not executed. Also strange is the first thing in the output is "Started by an SCM change", followed by an indication that there was in fact no change :/

Comment: on the project page there will be a link to the polling log, can you paste in the text found there?

Comment: Can you paste the output for the SVN polling log link on you Jenkins job page ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but it's solid advice.  As [Kosuke](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/) rants here - polling is sub-optimal.  I strongly suggest you implement a post commit hook as described in the [jenkins svn plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) wiki.

Comment: @gareth_bowles I just manually ran another test, with console output:
Started by user xxx
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on RTP-Dev in workspace /xxx/jenkins/SLAVE/workspace/SVN_Polling_Test
Updating https://xxx/svn/repos/xxx/xxx at revision '2014-01-10T18:19:00.484 +0000'
At revision 10398
no change for https://xxx/svn/repos/xxx/xxx since the previous build
[SVN_Polling_Test] $ /bin/sh -xe /xxx/jenkins/TMP/hudson223069737517875673.sh
+ echo blah
blah
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: And this is the matching SVN Polling Log:
Started on Jan 10, 2014 3:50:39 PM
Received SCM poll call on xxx for SVN_Polling_Test on Jan 10, 2014 3:51:40 PM
https://xxx/svn/repos/xxx/xxx is at revision 10,398
  (changed from 10,380)
Done. Took 1 min 1 sec
Changes found

Comment: Sounds the same as what we're seeing, Polling finds changes, the changes are actually really there, but then Jenkins incorrectly says "No changes." So when it runs the build, you wonder why it's running the build when nothing changed. Actually, it's because something changed, but it has a bug elsewhere. Annoying as hell, though, and still not fixed in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

check the scm url，if encode url may cause this problem,like:

https://example.com:8443/svn/%E7%A0%94/hm/prj%201.x

Comment: and make sure the svn server time is the same as your jenkins server

Comment: or add @HEAD at the end of scm url